# How to compute DECIMAL_DIG from value returned by mpfr_get_prec()?

Tags: floating-point, precision, mpfr

Context: C standard has `xxx_DECIMAL_DIG` macros, which can be used in `printf` to [`maintain precision of floating-point value`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value). Example for `double`:

```
printf("%.*g\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, x);
```

A simple question: how to compute the similar `DECIMAL_DIG` from value returned by `mpfr_get_prec`?

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpfr.h>

#define PREC 128

int prec2decimal_dig(int prec)
{
    return prec / 3;    // example, not accurate
}

int main (void)
{
    mpfr_t x;

    mpfr_init2(x, PREC);
    mpfr_set_d(x, 2.0 / 3.0, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_printf("%.*Rf\n", prec2decimal_dig(PREC), x);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc t78a.c -lmpfr -lgmp -oa && ./a
0.666666666666666629659232512494781985878944
```

What would be the precise implementation of `prec2decimal_dig`?

---

Extra: [`base-2: why DECIMAL_DIG - DIG == 2 or 3?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449728/base-2-why-decimal-dig-dig-2-or-3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, the native floating-point numbers are almost always in radix 2 (i.e. `FLT_RADIX` = 2 and *b* = 2 in the description of `DECIMAL_DIG` in the C standard), like MPFR. In this case, you can use `mpfr_get_str_ndigits` with radix *b* = 10 (note that *b* in the C standard is the input radix, i.e. 2, and *b* in the MPFR manual is the output radix, i.e. 10 in this context). This function is described as:

> Return the minimal integer *m* such that any number of *p* bits, when output with *m* digits in radix *b* with rounding to nearest, can be recovered exactly when read again, still with rounding to nearest. More precisely, we have *m* = 1 + ceil(*p* × log(2)/log(*b*)), with *p* replaced by *p* − 1 if *b* is a power of 2.

Note that if `FLT_RADIX` = 10 on your platform, `DECIMAL_DIG` is just *p*. And I don't know any other platform with another radix.

Comment: In [this](https://godbolt.org/z/r8hhGG5hs) program x is non-zero, but the printed value is zero. Why? How to fix?

Comment: @pmor You need to use the `g` format specifier, not `f`.

Comment: OK. Is there any solution for `f` _conversion_ specifier?

Comment: @pmor Note that if you consider the `f` conversion specifier, this is unrelated to `DECIMAL_DIG` (even with the native C floating-point types). Moreover, the needed precision obviously depends on the number. A straightforward solution could be to compute the exponent of the first nonzero digit in base 10; then compute the wanted precision for `f` using this value and `mpfr_get_str_ndigits`. But the obtained precision may not be optimal.

Comment: Thanks! I have to study more `DECIMAL_DIG` (obsolete with C23) and `%g`. I've asked the [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77156780/1778275) for native FP types.

Comment: @pmor `DECIMAL_DIG` is obsolescent in C23, but it is replaced by an equivalent macro for each standard floating-point type (instead of the widest floating-point type).

Answer (score 1):

`XXX_DECIMAL_DIG` is derived from:

- 'b', the base.  Examples: 2, 10, ...
- 'p', the number of digits (in base `b`) encoded, both explicitly or implicitly.

When `b` is a power of 10:

```
XXX_DECIMAL_DIG = p * log10(b)
```

Otherwise

```
XXX_DECIMAL_DIG = ceiling(1 + (p * log10(b)))
```

Use 28/93 for a fraction just larger than log<sub>10</sub>2.

Example for common `double`

```
DBL_DECIMAL_DIG = (int) ceil(1 + (53 * log10(2));
DBL_DECIMAL_DIG = (int) ceil(1 + (53 * 28.0/93));
DBL_DECIMAL_DIG = 1 + ((53 * 28 + 92)/93);
DBL_DECIMAL_DIG = 17;
```

---

```
#define LOG10_2_NUM 28
#define LOG10_2_DEN 93
int prec2decimal_dig(int prec) {
  return 1 + ((prec*28 + 92)/93);
  // or 
  return (prec*LOG10_2_NUM + LOG10_2_DEN*2 - 1)/LOG10_2_DEN;
}
```