# How to compute precision for conversion specification %.*f to maintain precision of floating-point value?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, precision

Note: this question originated from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19897395/1778275) answer.

How to compute precision for conversion specification `%.*f` to maintain precision of floating-point value?

Note: Here the "maintain precision" means that after the printed value is read back (for example, by `strtod` or by `scanf`) the resulted value is equal (except NaNs) to the original value (used for the printing with conversion specification `%.*f`).

Comment: When you say "the original value", I assume you mean the *printed* value?

Comment: Can you please show what you mean by using `sprintf` and `sscanf`?

Comment: Do you want a single value (number of digits) that works for all floating-point values that might be printed? Or a value that is computed for a specific floating-point value that is about to be printed? If the value is `DBL_TRUE_MIN`, do you really want to print the hundreds of digits necessary (324 with the usual `double` format)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I doubt it. Given a `double` (or `float`) `x`, `x` has a specific value, as defined by the floating-point format. Converting that to a string using `printf` with `%.*f` and then converting the string to the floating-point format using `scanf` would yield some resulting value, and getting the “original value” would mean that resulting value equals the initial floating-point value of `x`, regardless of what the interim string is.

Comment: @SimonGoater: Re “In general, you can't be sure it will be read back as the original value”: Each floating-point value can be represented sufficiently precisely in decimal that converting the decimal representation back to the floating-point format will produce the original value if done with correctly implemented routines. That is, there is always some number of digits that will do the job.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The original value means the value used for the printing with conversion specification `%.*f`. Question is updated.

Comment: @WeatherVane See my answer (trivial solution).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Re: "print the hundreds of digits": yes. Note: we can limit the number of digits to, say, N. If N is exceeded, we may fall back to `%.*e` or to `%a`.

Comment: @pmor: If you have a fallback to `%e`, then take the number of digits you would print with `%e` and add how many digits after the decimal place the decimal numeral will start (zero for immediately after “.”, negative if to the left). If the sum is negative, use zero, otherwise use the sum as the number of digits to print with `%f`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Extra question: if `sprintf` (for FP value) succeeded, then is it quarantined that `strtod` (for the array written by `sprintf`) will succeed (assuming that no UB occurred)? Was this question discussed before? Does this question need to be asked separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To round trip `double` (binary floating-point) values to decimal text via `"%.*f"` and back to the same value requires up to `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`(commonly 17) *significant* digits.

> `DBL_DECIMAL_DIGITS`
> number of decimal digits, n, such that any floating-point number with p radix b digits can be rounded to a floating-point number with n decimal digits and back again without change to the value,
> C23dr § 5.2.4.2.2 24

Any value magnitude >= 10<sup>DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1</sup> printed with `"%.0f"` will print at least `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` digits.  It is only values smaller than that may require some digits after the decimal point.

```
int prec = DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - log10(fabs(x));
if (prec < 0) {
  prec = 0;
}
printf("%.*f\n", prec, x);
```

---

- Care is needed with `int prec = DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - log10(fabs(x))` as values very close to a power-of-10 may incur computational errors that result in an off-by-one error.  Better to round and potential incur a +1 precision.
- Select `double` values may easily get by with fewer digits.  Could try with incrementally reducing precision.
- Infinites, NaN and zeros may needed special handing.
- Values about `-DBL_TRUE_MIN` likely needs the longest *string*.  This is about `2 /* "-0." */ - DBL_MIN_10_EXP + DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 1 /* \0 */`.

---

To find an optimal minimal format precision:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Buffer size needed for all `double`
#define BUF_N (3 /* "-0." */ - DBL_MIN_10_EXP + DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 1 /* \0 */)

// Untested code.  Grandparent duty calls.
// Needs review for off-by-1 errors.
int round_trip_precision_min(double x) {
  if (!isfinite(x) || x == 0.0) {
    return 0;
  }
  char buf[BUF_N + 10];  // 10 extra for margin
  int prec = (int) (DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - lround(log10(fabs(x))));
  if (prec < 0) {
    prec = 0;
  }
  // Try with less precision
  while (prec > 0) {
    sprintf(buf, "%.*f", prec - 1, x);
    if (atof(buf) != x) {
      break;
    }
    prec--;
  }
  return prec;
}
```

Comment: I've adapted the code for `float` (`FLT_`, 32-bit) and have tested it exhaustively. No errors found.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial solution is to pass x trough `sprintf` followed by `strtod` (produces y) until x = y:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define PREC_MAX 340

void print_f(double x, bool newline)
{
    double y;
    char s[PREC_MAX * 3]; // what is the precise multiplier ?
    bool f_printed = false;

    if (isnan(x) || isinf(x))
    {
        printf("%f", x);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int prec = 1; prec < PREC_MAX; ++prec)
        {
            if (sprintf(s, "%.*f", prec, x) > 0) // may encoding error occur ?
            {
                y = strtod(s, 0); // is there a real need of error handling ?
                if (x == y)
                {
                    printf("%s", s);
                    f_printed = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!f_printed)
        {
            printf("%.*g", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, x); 
        }
    }
    if (newline)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    print_f(0.000000000000000000000001617, true);   // 0.000000000000000000000001617
    print_f(1.0, true);                             // 1.0
    print_f(0x1p-27, true);                         // 0.000000007450580596923828
    print_f(NAN, true);                             // nan
    print_f(INFINITY, true);                        // inf
}
```

There may be a "loop free" constant time complexity solution, which is interesting to see. Extra question: can this solution be formally proven?

---

Extra: [Difference between `scanf()` and `strtol()` / `strtod()` in parsing numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425730/difference-between-scanf-and-strtol-strtod-in-parsing-numbers).

Comment: Try `print_f(-DBL_TRUE_MIN, 0)`.  Magic number 256  is too small.  A value about `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - DBL_MIN_10_EXP`, commonly more than 300, is needed.

Comment: Thanks! Test shows that it is 325. However, your formula (`(DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - lround(log10(fabs(x))))`) shows that it is 340. Changed to 340.

Comment: My formula may error, but hopefully only on the slightly too large size.  A dozen or so extra bytes is rarely a problem whereas insufficient buffer leads to a malfunction or worse.